# Issue with null value using select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to use this select statement but my issue is for this ID that i am trying to use in my select statement has null value.  Even though ID 542 has null value but i know for fact in the future is going to have a 'COMPLETE' value in it.  The 3 possible values for the FLAG field are COMPLETE, NOT COMPLETE AND NULL. What i want to achieve with this select statement is to see all records where FLAG is not 'COMPLETE'. If i run my query now, it will not return anything but if i remove FLAG <>'COMPLETE' then it will return the record ID 542 but the flag value is null.
 Here is my code

```
SELECT ID, DT, STAT FROM myTable WHERE ID = 542 and FLAG <> 'COMPLETE'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the NULL to text:

```
SELECT ID, DT, STAT 
FROM myTable 
WHERE ID = 542 and ISNULL(FLAG,'NULL') <> 'COMPLETE'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, DT, STAT 
FROM myTable 
WHERE ID = 542 and ISNULL(FLAG, 'NOT COMPLETE') <> 'COMPLETE'
```

Since the `FLAG` is null it cannot be compared against 'COMPLETE' and you're missing the entry...

or:

```
SELECT ID, DT, STAT 
FROM myTable 
WHERE ID = 542 AND (FLAG <> 'COMPLETE' OR FLAG IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SQL's three valued logic!  The well-known brothers `true` and `false` have a secret stepsister called `unknown`.  And the result of a comparison with `null` is always `unknown`.

A quick fix is to add an explicit `is null` check:

```
where Flag is null or Flag <> 'COMPLETE'
```

Note that `not unknown` is still `unknown`, so this won't work:

```
where not Flag = 'COMPLETE' -- Won't work
```

In fact, not even `null` is equal to `null`.  But `null` isn't not equal to `null` either!

For more fun, have a look at Wikipedia.  It has a whole page dedicated to [three valued logic in SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29).